# Is Lombok Compatible with .getConstructor()?

Tags: java, reflection, lombok

I'm trying to use reflection to call the constructor generated by Lombok using @RequiredArgsConstructor (with no [staticName](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor) param).

```
Class.forName("path.to.class")
                    .getConstructor(classes)
                    .newInstance(params);
```

but I get a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException` error. Using .getDeclaredMethod() instead of .getConstructor() works for any of the other methods, but not a constructor of the same name as the class.

Does Lombok generate some weird constructor that is not recognized by .getConstructor()?

Comment: This should just work. Can you give the full code of the annotated class, so I can help? Is it an inner class? In that case, you get an invisible extra first parameter, containing a reference to the outer class. That has nothing to do with Lombok, that's just what java does.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that two of the class parameters were switched. I printed out the result from .getConstructors() and found the mismatch.